# How to send the pins in the map view back to the call out view?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, mkmapview

I am implementing MAPKit Based application, In that I had a problem with the pins display. Some times they are coming on top of the callOut view. I used the following code to send the pins back:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
 {
          for (MKAnnotationView* annotationView in views) 
         {

              [mapView sendSubviewToBack:annotationView];
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't remember if the callout bubble is a subview of the annotationView, if it is the following should work...
If you're coding for iOS 4.0 and above you can use these

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotView {
     [mapView sendSubviewToBack:annotView];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotView {  
     [mapView bringSubviewToFront:annotView];   
}
```

Otherwise try implementing inside the annotationView

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        UIView *mySuperview = self.superview;
        while (mySuperview && ![mySuperview isKindOfClass:[MKMapView class]]) {
            mySuperview = mySuperview.superview;
        }
        if (mySuperview) {
            [mySuperview bringSubviewToFront:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In `IOS 5` and `IOS 6` , I try this and it's ok

the pin never overlap CalloutView.
I use custom calloutview , in file Base calloutView I add this :

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
```